# Unable to match url with regex when there are two underscores

Tags: regex

```
url: local/veg-lover/Keep-Loop_Austin_AT
```

Earlier i was using `/veg-lover/(.*)`
It was matching but now i have to check for only two underscores in url.

Comment: What is your requirement, your previous pattern should work with this URL as well.

Comment: I need to match the last string (i.e. Keep-Loop_Austin_AT)  containing   with only 2 underscores.

Comment: So local/veg-lover/ABC-DEF_Austin_AT shoudl match and it should not match for  local/veg-lover/ABC-DEF_Austin-AT

Answer (score 0):

```
/veg-lover/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern

```
/veg-lover/.+?_.+?_.+
```

makes sure that you have two underscores in the last part, with the underscores appearing between words and not only two underscores, or starting or ending with underscore

Answer (score 0):

```
/veg-lover/([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*)
```

you guarantee there are only two underscores in the part of the URL you want capture.